# BVT's after Jenkins build on Perforce VC

Tags: jenkins, build, perforce, verification

I have set up a [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins) project using the [Perforce Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin) and am now working on configuring the "Publish JUnit test result report" post-build action so that it will run build verification tests upon successful builds.

It's telling me that I need to "first set up your build to run tests" - but I am unsure if I should be doing this via Visual Studio since I don't have TFS. Is there another way to do this apart from TFS?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by using MSTest and its [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin). For those of you here with the same question I had, you can find some pretty good directions on how to get this working [here](http://munleeuw.blogspot.com/2013/08/making-it-rain-running-ms-test-unit.html) (although I used the version you can find in VS 2012).